# Android: Modifying kernel parameter during runtime

Tags: android, kernel

In my android app, I'm trying to ping a large number of devices (say 4000). By default, the icmp_ratelimit under /proc/sys/net/ipv4 is set at 1000, thus restricting the number of pings being sent. Is it possible to change this parameter during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not.  Android restricts where normal apps can read/write on the filesystem.  /dev, /proc and /sys are all restricted areas that normal applications cannot access for writing.  To do this you'd have to either have a rooted device which has su added to it or a custom ROM.